# How to find checksum of a list of files and print them together

Tags: python, checksum

I have a list of filenames and I wish to find the checksum of the each file and store in a list displaying [filename,checksum].

New to programming so I tried creating a for loop taking the files from directory. I then used hashlib.md5 to open file with its path and print the filename alongside the checksum.

```
directory = os.listdir(path)
    def file_as_bytes(file):
                with file:
                    return file.read()
    for fx in directory:
        pass
        print[(fx, hashlib.md5(file_as_bytes(open(fx, 'rb'))).digest())]
```

This is the error I obtain:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c.txt'
```

Which I never created in my client.
I only wish to display the checksum of each file that I have in my client (that already exist)

Comment: `open(...).read()` is shorter than `file_as_bytes(open(...))` =)

Comment: and you definitely want to print `.hexdigest()`, not `.digest()` of md5, because the latter is pretty much binary and contains unprintable characters.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
open(fx, 'rb')
```

use:

```
open(os.path.join( path, fx), 'rb')
```